# Installed xorg on server, no screens found

Tags: 12.04, xorg

All:

Followed this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Performing startx says no screens found... ???

Comment: For some reason after following those instructions, I do NOT have an xorg.conf file...

Comment: OK, so someone should add this to the ServerGUI page:

I had to do:

sudo Xorg -configure
sudo cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf

This should really be spelled out in that servergui page, as mentioned above.  Took me 30 minutes of searching.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't add answer myself.  Silly, that.

Comment: You'll be able to self-answer after a waiting period.

Comment: You *can* and *should* answer the question yourself.  Just start typing into the "Your Answer" box at the bottom and when finished click the button "Post your answer"

Answer (score 4):

[From the OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232392/installed-xorg-on-server-no-screens-found#comment287223_232392), the solution:

> OK, so someone should add this to the ServerGUI page: I had to do: `sudo Xorg -configure` and `sudo cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` This should really be spelled out in that [servergui page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI), as mentioned above. Took me 30 minutes of searching. – Matt

Comment: Does not work here, it is FreeBSD though. This is some sort of video card driver error I think.

Comment: Turned out I had to install closed source nvidia drivers and load them as kernel module.