# Cannot get to desktop

Tags: 16.04

I am stuck on the screen before loading into the desktop,before I was trying to install gallium nine drivers, which in someway caused this to happen.

Edit 1: installed default GPU drivers to no avail.

Edit 2: tried to reset unity, unable to due to their being no variable set.

[image]

Edit 3:  I've tried to edit in nomodeset, through tty and also multiple others with consistent failure and no change whatsoever, and for one i cannot even find the problem as I've seen this screen on boot up, and it was never a problem.

Edit 4: tried other possible solutions, no luck on any of those, but will continue the search.

Edit 5: by typing startx in tty I got a fatal server error saying no screens found.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/856346/edit) your question and add a screenshot.

Comment: Search for re-install unity desktop

Comment: I was able to download some packages, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Nope, nothing worked, possibly because the problem isn't from installing Ubuntu, since I've had this running fine for a while till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching google with my last edit in mind I found this link [Installed xorg on server, no screens found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232392/installed-xorg-on-server-no-screens-found)

which was similar but not exactly the same, but by using the first answerer's first command helped me find the problem which was 20-radeon.conf which I then deleted the file through tty, finally fixing the problem.